# Closure Compiler is outputting a zero byte file with a Makefile

Tags: makefile, google-closure-compiler

I made some modifications to [SVG Edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com) which contains a make file. When I compile the source with a freshly cloned repo it compiles successfully, but when I do it on my local repo it seems to comply successfully but it results in a svgedit.compiled.js file of Zero byes. No warnings whatsoever.

This is my (modified) Make file:

```
NAME=svg-edit
VERSION=2.6
PACKAGE=$(NAME)-$(VERSION)
MAKEDOCS=naturaldocs/NaturalDocs
CLOSURE=build/tools/closure-compiler.jar
ZIP=zip

# All files that will be compiled by the Closure compiler.

JS_FILES=\
  js-hotkeys/jquery.hotkeys.min.js \
  jquerybbq/jquery.bbq.min.js \
  svgicons/jquery.svgicons.js \
  jquery.jgraduate.min.js \
  spinbtn/JQuerySpinBtn.min.js \
  touch.js \
    contextmenu/jquery.contextmenu.js \
    browser.js \
    svgtransformlist.js \
    math.js \
    units.js \
    svgutils.js \
    sanitize.js \
    history.js \
    select.js \
    draw.js \
    path.js \
    svgcanvas.js \
    svg-editor.js \
    contextmenu.js \
    locale/locale.js

JS_INPUT_FILES=$(addprefix editor/, $(JS_FILES))
JS_BUILD_FILES=$(addprefix build/$(PACKAGE)/, $(JS_FILES))
CLOSURE_JS_ARGS=$(addprefix --js , $(JS_INPUT_FILES))
COMPILED_JS=editor/svgedit.compiled.js

#all: release firefox opera
all: release

# The build directory relies on the JS being compiled.
build/$(PACKAGE): $(COMPILED_JS)
    rm -rf config
    mkdir config
    if [ -x $(MAKEDOCS) ] ; then $(MAKEDOCS) -i editor/ -o html docs/ -p config/ -oft -r ; fi

    # Make build directory and copy all editor contents into it
    mkdir -p build/$(PACKAGE)
    cp -r editor/* build/$(PACKAGE)

    # Remove all hidden .svn directories
    -find build/$(PACKAGE) -name .svn -type d | xargs rm -rf {} \;
    -find build/$(PACKAGE) -name .git -type d | xargs rm -rf {} \;

    # Create the release version of the main HTML file.
    build/tools/ship.py --i=editor/svg-editor.html --on=svg_edit_release > build/$(PACKAGE)/svg-editor.html

# NOTE: Some files are not ready for the Closure compiler: (jquery)
# NOTE: Our code safely compiles under SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
# NOTE: Our code is *not* ready for ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
# NOTE: WHITESPACE_ONLY and --formatting PRETTY_PRINT is helpful for debugging.
$(COMPILED_JS):
    java -jar $(CLOSURE) \
        --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS \
        $(CLOSURE_JS_ARGS) \
        --js_output_file $(COMPILED_JS)
        --warning_level=VERBOSE

compile: $(COMPILED_JS)

release: build/$(PACKAGE)
    cd build ; $(ZIP) $(PACKAGE).zip -r $(PACKAGE) ; cd ..
    tar -z -c -f build/$(PACKAGE)-src.tar.gz \
        --exclude='\.svn' \
        --exclude='\.git' \
        --exclude='build/*' \
        .

clean:
    rm -rf config
    rm -rf build/$(PACKAGE)
    rm -rf $(COMPILED_JS)
```

This is the output when I `make`:

```
rm -rf config
mkdir config
if [ -x naturaldocs/NaturalDocs ] ; then naturaldocs/NaturalDocs -i editor/ -o html docs/ -p config/ -oft -r ; fi
# Make build directory and copy all editor contents into it
mkdir -p build/svg-edit-2.6
cp -r editor/* build/svg-edit-2.6
# Remove all hidden .svn directories
find build/svg-edit-2.6 -name .svn -type d | xargs rm -rf {} \;
find build/svg-edit-2.6 -name .git -type d | xargs rm -rf {} \;
# Create the release version of the main HTML file.
build/tools/ship.py --i=editor/svg-editor.html --on=svg_edit_release > build/svg-edit-2.6/svg-editor.html
cd build ; zip svg-edit-2.6.zip -r svg-edit-2.6 ; cd ..
updating: svg-edit-2.6/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/browser-not-supported.html (deflated 53%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/browser.js (deflated 72%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/canvg/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/canvg/canvg.js (deflated 79%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/canvg/rgbcolor.js (deflated 69%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/contextmenu/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/contextmenu/jquery.contextMenu.js (deflated 71%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/contextmenu.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/draginput.js (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/draw.js (deflated 71%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/embedapi.html (deflated 53%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/embedapi.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/closepath_icons.svg (deflated 70%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-arrows.js (deflated 66%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-closepath.js (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-connector.js (deflated 70%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-eyedropper.js (deflated 69%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-foreignobject.js (deflated 66%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-grid.js (deflated 66%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-helloworld.js (deflated 56%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-imagelib.js (deflated 68%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-imagelib.xml (deflated 68%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-markers.js (deflated 68%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-server_moinsave.js (deflated 52%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-server_opensave.js (deflated 65%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-shapes.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/ext-shapes.xml (deflated 38%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/eyedropper-icon.xml (deflated 48%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/eyedropper.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/fileopen.php (deflated 37%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/filesave.php (deflated 52%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/foreignobject-icons.xml (deflated 76%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/grid-icon.xml (deflated 71%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/helloworld-icon.xml (deflated 52%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/imagelib/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/imagelib/index.html (deflated 51%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/imagelib/smiley.svg (deflated 64%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/markers-icons.xml (deflated 87%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/animal.json (deflated 50%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/arrow.json (deflated 55%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/dialog_balloon.json (deflated 58%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/electronics.json (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/flowchart.json (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/game.json (deflated 48%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/math.json (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/misc.json (deflated 4%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/music.json (deflated 55%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/object.json (deflated 52%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/raphael.txt (deflated 47%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/raphael_1.json (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/raphael_2.json (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/social.json (deflated 56%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/symbol.json (deflated 53%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/ui.json (deflated 64%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/extensions/shapelib/weather.json (deflated 68%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Anivers-webfont.eot (deflated 47%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Anivers-webfont.ttf (deflated 47%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Anivers-webfont.woff (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/fanwood-webfont.eot (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/fanwood-webfont.svg (deflated 84%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/fanwood-webfont.ttf (deflated 70%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/fanwood-webfont.woff (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/fanwood_italic-webfont.eot (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/fanwood_italic-webfont.svg (deflated 81%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/fanwood_italic-webfont.ttf (deflated 66%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/fanwood_italic-webfont.woff (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/fertigo-webfont.eot (deflated 46%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/fertigo-webfont.ttf (deflated 46%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/fertigo-webfont.woff (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Junction-webfont.eot (deflated 35%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Junction-webfont.svg (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Junction-webfont.ttf (deflated 35%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Junction-webfont.woff (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/League_Gothic-webfont.eot (deflated 48%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/League_Gothic-webfont.svg (deflated 75%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/League_Gothic-webfont.ttf (deflated 48%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/League_Gothic-webfont.woff (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Museo_Slab-webfont.eot (deflated 48%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Museo_Slab-webfont.ttf (deflated 48%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Museo_Slab-webfont.woff (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Museo_Slab_Italic-webfont.eot (deflated 49%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Museo_Slab_Italic-webfont.ttf (deflated 49%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-files/Museo_Slab_Italic-webfont.woff (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/.DS_Store (deflated 91%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/font-selector.js (deflated 68%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/.DS_Store (deflated 96%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/fanwood.css (deflated 75%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/font-images/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/font-images/brush-script.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/font-images/cloister.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/font-images/cooper.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/font-images/fanwood.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/font-images/junction.png (deflated 1%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/font-images/league_gothic.png (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/Junction.css (deflated 59%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/fonts/League_Gothic.css (deflated 60%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/font-selector/README.md (deflated 59%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/history.js (deflated 80%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-bottom.png (deflated 4%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-bottom.svg (deflated 81%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-center.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-center.svg (deflated 81%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-left.png (deflated 3%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-left.svg (deflated 79%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-middle.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-middle.svg (deflated 81%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-right.png (deflated 1%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-right.svg (deflated 79%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-top.png (deflated 4%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/align-top.svg (deflated 79%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/bold.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/cancel.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/circle.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/clear.png (deflated 3%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/clone.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/conn.svg (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/copy.png (deflated 3%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/cross.png (deflated 3%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/cut.png (deflated 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/delete.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/document-properties.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/dropdown.gif (deflated 8%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/ellipse.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/eye.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/eyedropper.png (deflated 8%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/fhpath.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/flyouth.png (deflated 5%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/flyup.gif (deflated 6%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/freehand-circle.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/freehand-square.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/go-down.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/go-up.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/image.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/italic.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/line.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/link_controls.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/logo.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/logo.svg (deflated 42%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/move_bottom.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/move_top.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/node_clone.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/node_delete.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/none.png (deflated 3%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/open.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/paste.png (deflated 2%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/path.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/pencil.png (deflated 1%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/placeholder.svg (deflated 50%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/polygon.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/polygon.svg (deflated 74%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/README.txt (deflated 82%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/rect.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/redo.png (deflated 2%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/reorient.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/rotate.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/save.png (deflated 1%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/select.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/select_node.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/sep.png (deflated 4%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/shape_group.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/shape_ungroup.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/source.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/spinbtn_updn_big.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/square.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/svg_edit_icons.svg (deflated 77%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/svg_edit_icons.svgz (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/text.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/text.svg (deflated 70%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/to_path.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/undo.png (deflated 1%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/view-refresh.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/wave.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/wireframe.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/images/zoom.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/css/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/css/jgraduate.css (deflated 74%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/css/jPicker.css (deflated 79%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/AlphaBar.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/bar-opacity.png (deflated 4%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/Bars.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/eyedropper.png (deflated 8%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/map-opacity.png (deflated 4%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/mappoint.gif (deflated 6%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/mappoint_c.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/mappoint_f.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/Maps.png (deflated 5%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/NoColor.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/picker.gif (deflated 3%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/preview-opacity.png (deflated 3%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/rangearrows.gif (deflated 3%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/images/rangearrows2.gif (deflated 8%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/jpicker.min.js (deflated 84%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/jquery.jgraduate.js (deflated 75%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/jquery.jgraduate.min.js (deflated 69%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/LICENSE (deflated 65%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jgraduate/README (deflated 13%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jquery-ui/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js (deflated 74%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js (deflated 75%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jquery.js (deflated 65%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jquerybbq/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/jquerybbq/jquery.bbq.min.js (deflated 50%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/js-hotkeys/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/js-hotkeys/jquery.hotkeys.min.js (deflated 44%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/js-hotkeys/README.md (deflated 44%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.af.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.ar.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.az.js (deflated 64%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.be.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.bg.js (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.ca.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.cs.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.cy.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.da.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.de.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.el.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.en.js (deflated 64%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.es.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.et.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.fa.js (deflated 65%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.fi.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.fr.js (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.fy.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.ga.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.gl.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.he.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.hi.js (deflated 67%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.hr.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.hu.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.hy.js (deflated 64%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.id.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.is.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.it.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.ja.js (deflated 59%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.ko.js (deflated 59%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.lt.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.lv.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.mk.js (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.ms.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.mt.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.nl.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.no.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.pl.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.pt-BR.js (deflated 64%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.pt-PT.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.ro.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.ru.js (deflated 66%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.sk.js (deflated 60%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.sl.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.sq.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.sr.js (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.sv.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.sw.js (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.test.js (deflated 64%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.th.js (deflated 66%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.tl.js (deflated 63%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.tr.js (deflated 61%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.uk.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.vi.js (deflated 62%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.yi.js (deflated 64%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.zh-CN.js (deflated 58%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.zh-HK.js (deflated 58%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/lang.zh-TW.js (deflated 56%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/locale.js (deflated 68%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/locale/README.txt (deflated 48%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/math.js (deflated 67%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/path.js (deflated 72%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/sanitize.js (deflated 74%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/select.js (deflated 70%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/spinbtn/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/spinbtn/JQuerySpinBtn.css (deflated 47%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/spinbtn/JQuerySpinBtn.js (deflated 65%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/spinbtn/JQuerySpinBtn.min.js (deflated 68%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/spinbtn/spinbtn_updn.png (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/svg-editor.css (deflated 79%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/svg-editor.html (deflated 76%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/svg-editor.js (deflated 73%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/svg-editor.manifest (deflated 74%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/svgcanvas.js (deflated 74%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/svgedit.compiled.js (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/svgicons/ (stored 0%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/svgicons/jquery.svgicons.js (deflated 64%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/svgtransformlist.js (deflated 68%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/svgutils.js (deflated 65%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/touch.js (deflated 59%)
updating: svg-edit-2.6/units.js (deflated 66%)
tar -z -c -f build/svg-edit-2.6-src.tar.gz \
        --exclude='\.svn' \
        --exclude='\.git' \
        --exclude='build/*' \
```

My question is how to properly debug what is going wrong, I tried adding `--warning_level=VERBOSE` to Closure Compiler but the output looks the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since make had compiled once, it didn't execute the closure compiler on subsequent runs, so no message error were displaying. You need to make with...

`make -B`